# Calculate the price based upon inserted date in php

Tags: php

I'm here trying to make a scenario, where I visit a juice shop to ask the juice seller to provide juice until a certain date, by providing him a certain amount he will provide me juice service until by balance will over.

```
$rate = 30;  //rate of per juice glass
$total_amt = 200; //amt that provide to the seller at start of the service
$start_date = "19-08-2022"; //date of starting the service

$cost = $rate * 7; //rate * days
if($cost <= $total_amt){
    echo "Remainder:".$total_amt - $cost; //Money that seller give back to buyer
} else {
 echo "you need to pay extra:".$cost - $total_amt; //money need to pay exta for glass
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/EP8Et)

I'm unable to figure out, how can I calculate the number of glass that comes inside $200 based upon the service start date and the next due date.

**Example:**

In **$200** amount, the buyer will get **6 glass** with returing balance **$20**, because If the buyer service start date is **19-08-2022** then the due date is **25-08-2022** (19 + 6 = 25)

**So, the output needs to be like:**

```
Number of glass in $200 is: 6
returning balance : $20
next due date: 25-08-2022
```

Comment: So what you want is the `next due date`, and not the actual price? please be precise in your question

Comment: I want to return the number of glasses and next due date, returning balance is not a big deal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Calculation of the due date:**

- **GIVEN** a start date (as in your example)
- **GIVEN** the interval (as in your example)

You can easily calculate the according target date via:

- Initiate a [DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php), with your given start date, according to your specified format:

`DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", "19-08-2022")`

- Create your [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.construct.php). Given an amount of days, for example two days, the according string you need to pass would need to be: `P2D`:

`new DateInterval('P2D')`

- Now you just need to add your `DateInterval` onto your `DateTime` via the [add](https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.add.php) method, and you get your resulting `DateTime` object:

```
var_dump( DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", "19-08-2022")->add(new DateInterval('P2D')) );
```

**Calculation of the amount of glasses that can be afforded:**

If one class costs `$glass_price`, and you have a total amount of `$money_available`, you can simply calculate the amount of glasses you can afford via:

`floor($money_available / $glass_price)`

**Calculation of the remaining amount:**

And for the returning balance, you would do:

`$money_available % $glass_price`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @DevelJoe for providing the way to calculate the next due date

```
$rate = 30;
$total_amt = 200;
$start_date = "19-08-2022";

$days  = floor($total_amt / $rate); // provide number of days 
$glasses = $days; //each day means 1 glass 
$cost = $rate * $days; //calculating the per day cost with days
$due_date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $start_date)->add(new DateInterval('P'.$days.'D'));
if($cost <= $total_amt){
    $bal = $total_amt % $cost;
    var_dump(array("glasses"=>$glasses, "buyer_bal"=> $bal, "due_date"=>$due_date->format('d-m-Y')));
} else {
   $bal = $cost % $total_amt;
   var_dump(array("glasses"=>$glasses, "buyer_bal"=> $bal, "due_date"=>$due_date->format('d-m-Y')));
}
```

**Output**

```
 array(3) {
  ["glasses"]=>
  float(6)  //<-----------Glasses
  ["returing_bal"]=>
  int(20)  //<------------Return Balance
  ["due_date"]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2022-08-25 14:09:02.000000"  //<----Next due date
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
  }
}
```